# How can I block traffic from this referrer?

Tags: google-analytics, htaccess, traffic, referrer

I'm getting a lot of spam referral traffic from `semalt.semalt.com/referral` on my website. I took a look at the link and there’s very little information about this.

The number of website visits is 185 this month, and they result in a 100% bounce rate.

So how I can block this website?

Comment: What web server? Apache? IIS? I can help with .htaccess.

Comment: web server is Apache

Comment: I get a bunch of these referrals too, but since I study this stuff, I allow it.

Comment: This should work. I used an older example .htaccess that has a lot of entries in it. Let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 2):

This should work...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} semalt\.semalt\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

...will force a 403 error. Otherwise...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} semalt\.semalt\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://www.gosomewhereelse.com [R,L]
```

... will send them some where else. (just change the domain name please.)

Comment: semalt original url is www.semalt.com  and in my google analytics shows in semalt.semalt.com/referral so which url i add

Comment: I have semalt.semalt.com as the referral here. But if you want, you can just use semalt.com. If you are not aware of regular expressions, I intentionally did not use ^ and $ which denote the beginning of the expression and the end. In this case, semalt.com will match semalt.semalt.com just fine.

Comment: What do you mean by "semalt _original url_ is www.semalt.com"? ... just to be sure that `semalt.com` is not the domain of _your_ site? Also, since the `RewriteCond` pattern is a regular expression (as closetnoc suggests), the `.` (period) should strictly be escaped to match a literal `.` rather than any character, ie. `semalt\.semalt\.com`.

Comment: @w3d Yes. You are technically correct! I edited the answer to make the change. Regex in .htaccess assumes, or at least used to, that text/domain specification was possible and was rather forgiving, hence my examples are probably more lazy than they should be. I would rather be technically correct and so I appreciate the flag. My examples did work okay when Apache 2.2 was released, but it is far better to CYA of course. Thanks again for the reminder!!